# Table fixed column not working when the description is on two rows in the same td

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to create a table with a fixed column but I faced all sorts of problems. 
For example:
the position is not ok because can easily distinguish the fixed column from the rest of tbody table and if I'll resize browser the fixed column will ruin table design. The background color of td from fixed column is not the same as in rest of tbody and most important is the the description of a column is displayed on more rows in the same tr td the height of td from fixed column will remain smaller than rest of tr as can be seen on last tr from my example.
Can anyone help me with this?

```
Please check my fiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/81/

Thank You.

Comment: I don't understand why you need this column, I am sure there are much better ways to get a column. What is the goal you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @Huangism Can you give me few example how to do that?

Comment: can you explain why you need this column the way it is? I don't get why you need it there. I think there is a better approach to what you want to do that's why I need to know what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Huangism I need that fixed column because I have a scrollable table with 200% width. The fixed column will keep the action buttons for each tr from table. Something like this fiddle:    http://jsfiddle.net/Ksb2W/44/                                 but this is very complicated and I don't think will be possible to integrate that on my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright so you can set this up a little bit differently

```
<table id='main'>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                use this div to define width of the viewable area
                <table>
                    this is your table with the data
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>action table here, don't need special positioning</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

use defined width, if you use % then you need to apply that to both tables so they both resize but I think defined width would be better. If you don't understand my code, let me know